# Help setting up region for double integral

Tags: integration

The integral I have is

$$\int_D \frac{y}{1+x^2} dA$$ where D is the strip $$0 < y < 1$$ in the xy-plane.

I'm not sure how to set up the 2 regions or how I am supposed to imagine this region on a graph. The furthest I got was the outer integration but I can't get the inner one
$$\int_0^1 \int\frac{y}{1+x^2}dx dy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The strip has finite height but runs along the entire length of the $x$-axis.

Comment: so does that mean that this would diverge?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx= arctan(x)|_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \pi$